# How to fill floated element to parent

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with filling my elements to the parent.

**html**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="left">
        Some big content that should be big.
    </div>
    <div class="menu">Some menu</div>
    <div class="right">
        Small content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .content{
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}

.right{
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}

.menu{
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qrjt8ys7/3/

On this example I would like to fill both blue and red elements. Depending on the content once the blue one is bigger, next time the red one.

The wrapper actually doesn't make it easier because I can't use absolute positioning (or I don't know how to do that).

Can I do that with CSS or should I do the ugly calculations in JS ?

Comment: So what you want is basically _equal height columns_ …? If so, that is a topic that has been more than discussed to death already.

Comment: Not exactly, the menu should be on top, so the right column should be smaller of the menu's height.
And I tried table and table-column styles, this solution gave the best effects I had, but I have lost the content of the right column ;o (the right column had 0x0 dimensions but was visible).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put something like this:

```
 <div class="left">
    <p>
    Small content
    </p>
</div>
```

or  insted of paragraph
I have edit your jsbin.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I can sugest you this solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/wmk4w81m/1/

```
.content{
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.left{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

.right{
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}

.menu{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
}

.wrapper{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution cuts off the first blue content.. But nice try, maybe this is the way :) I will play with that for a little, maybe I could fix that.

Comment: @MiłoszWieczorek well, you are right.. I can suggest you to use flex-box instead of block divs. It is very powerful tool: http://chriswrightdesign.com/experiments/using-flexbox-today/

Comment: That looks nice. I'll see whether it could help me ;)